# How to delete rows from a numpy 2D matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy, rows, mean

I am trying to remove the rows which have their mean equal to 0. I have tried this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((4,4))

for i in range(len(a)):

    if (i%2)==0 : a[i]= np.arange(4*i,4*(i+1))

    array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
           [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
           [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.],
           [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])        

np.ma.MaskedArray(a, mask=(np.mean(a,0)==0))
np.ma.compress_rows(a)
```

I would like to get this:

```
a =([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
     [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.]])
```

Comment: Just a word of caution: This won't be a problem for this example, but `==` comparisons for float data might cause problems because of the finite machine precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using index and conditions

```
In [187]: a[~(a.mean(axis=1)==0)]
Out[187]:
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
       [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.]])
```